# Output external image with cURL, but how do you change the width of the image?

Tags: php, curl, width

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$url = $_GET['url']; 

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 

$file = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);

echo $file;
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can change the width of `$file` to 300px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is heading for a browser inside an `<img>` tag, then you can get the browser to rescale it by changing the `width` attribute.

Otherwise you need to grab the file and rescale it in your PHP code before outputting it.

You can use [imagecopyresampled()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) to do that, calculating the height.  Then outputting the result.

Example, following on from obtaining the image in to `$file` from the code above.

```
$img = @imagecreatefromstring($file);

if ($img === false) {
    echo $file;
    exit;
}

$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

$newWidth = 300;

$ratio = $newWidth / $width;
$newHeight = $ratio * $height;


$resized = @imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

if ($resized === false) {
    echo $file;
    exit;
}

$quality = 90;

if (@imagecopyresampled($resized, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height)) {
    @imagejpeg($resized, NULL, $quality);
} else {
    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply! i tried list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file); echo $width; but getimagesize doesn't work for some reason, and i don't know how else i would get the original size.

Comment: @krysis: In the event of an error, it'll try and send the original file, so if you are using it within an `<img>` tag, best to set the width on it, you should anyway.  Beware of running out of memory on the server if the filesize is big.

Comment: will do! and thanks for the help again! really appreciate it :)